# Adding additional field and validation to Devise view/model in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, devise

I generated the default [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise) views with:

```
rails generate devise:views
```

Then I added a `username` field to the `views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb` form.

Currently, only `email` and `password` validation occurs.  How do I validate presence and uniqueness of the `username` field? Do I need to add something to the `User` model?

Answer (score 20):

I used both the of the tutorials mentioned in the other answers, [Railscast #210](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise) and the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address). However, so far as I could tell they do not explicitly say how to validate the presence and/or uniqueness of the username field.

If you added username with a simple migration -

```
rails generate migration addUsernameToUser username:string
```

Then devise doesn't do anything special with that field, so you need to add checks for validation and uniqueness yourself in the User model.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
```

However, If you look at the RailsCast #209 there is an example of the migration used to create the User model.

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration  
  def self.up  
    create_table(:users) do |t|  
      t.database_authenticatable :null => false  
      # t.confirmable  
      t.recoverable  
      t.rememberable  
      t.trackable  
      # t.lockable :lock_strategy => :failed_attempts, :unlock_strategy => :both  

      t.timestamps  
    end  

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true  
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true  
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true  
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true  
  end  

  def self.down  
    drop_table :users  
  end  
end
```

Notice here that the users email is defined as being unique. Perhaps if username was added using this same syntax then devise magic would take care of presence and uniqueness.

Comment: I did as you said validates_presence_of :username and 
  validates_uniqueness_of :username in my "user" model,how would i make when the error appears,the "name error" to be the first on the list,of errors,when they are displayed?

Answer (score 14):

**Rails 4 and Strong Parameters**

On top of the above I had to generate the views with:

```
$ rails g devise:views
```

then in `devise.rb` add:

```
config.scoped_views = true
```

and finally configure the permitted parameters as below for `sign_up` as below:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
        u.permit :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
      end
    end
end
```

[This is described in Devise Doc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#strong-parameters)

Also, my validation for `username` is the following:

```
validates :username, presence: true
validates :username, uniqueness: true, if: -> { self.username.present? }
```

I use two lines, so if `username` is blank I get only one error.

Comment: How would you preserve these new parameters if validation fails? Right now, only email is preserved.

Comment: uhm... I can't check right now, but I'd first check in the controller and make sure it returns a `@user` object containing those values. Maybe the email is the only field recorded because the object is empty and the browser fills it in. Just shooting from the hips

Comment: also check that the template is rendered in the same action and there is no redirection, in which case, again, the `@user` will be empty.  If you have overwritten the views, check in the view that the values are there.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is wondering how to get the login to check for username if its blank 
or to make sure to users cannot have the same username. I spent quite a few 
hours trying to figure this out and in the ned I only had to add :

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, case_sensitive: false
validates_presence_of :username
```

to your user.rb file in app/models/

Here are the docs...
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

This now throws the errors I need. 
I feel like an idiot because I found uniquness_of first , then went back to and spent hours trying to figure out how to check for a blank field then found it is in the same documentation as the other...I am a noob.

Now onto figure out how to change the error messages since they are not in the devise.en.yml

Answer (score -2):

Just add a username field to your User model and on the Devise wiki:
http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Sign-in-using-login-or-mail

Hope it helps.

Comment: That link is broken. Perhaps next time you could put the necessary information in your answer?

Comment: The link now redirects to the top level of the Devise wiki. Since I didn't know the Wiki was there, I found the link helpful. Probably the specific answer is now https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign_in-using-their-username-or-email-address, though as lashleigh says, that article does not address _validating_ the username in the model.

Comment: This just doesn't work anymore in Rails 4. It's not easy anymore.