# How to add additional validations for the Devise sign up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Let's say I have devise with default `RegistrationsController`. I'd like to add additional validation to `create` action. I'd like to have this validation only on this action as is not necessary for other places. How I can achieve this without copy&paste current `create` implementation ?

Comment: meaning just additional fields?  Say `username` or `address` ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692905/adding-additional-field-and-validation-to-devise-view-model-in-rails-app

Comment: No, I'm using nested attributes and I'd like to check if number of created objects is proper but I don't want to have to create everywhere associated records where User record is involved..